# debugging dynamically loaded url - need of example

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, dynamic

I cannot figure out how to use `//# sourceURL` to debug dynamically loaded html. My js file is:

```
"use strict";
(function() {
// Localize jQuery variable
let jQuery;

//part loading jQuery if needed
{...}

/******** My main function ********/
function main() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        let url = "http://localhost:5004/static/widget.html";
        $("#widget").load(url);
       
    });
}
```

I would like to be able to debug `http://localhost:5004/static/widget.html` if there is any error (in this html other js scripts are called). So I tried to add:

`//# sourceURL=filename.html` which shows me filename.html in my debugger but has incorrect URL
`//# sourceURL=http://localhost:5004/static/widget.html` does not work at all, the error points to `load()` line from my script.

How to use that correctly so that I actually can debug whatever is loaded into that div? Could you please give me correct, working example?

Comment: Totally unclear what you mean by *"debug whatever is loaded"*. Please elaborate in more detail

Comment: In this case I would like to be able to debug scripts that are included in widget.html file.

Comment: Debug in what way? Still being far too vague. Please provide more detail and a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Use on error in the tag as attribute `<tag id="wrapper" onerror="loadException()">`